# Открытие файла без указания названия файла с определенного каталога

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день.
На объекте настроил открытие файла с указанием имени файла и расширением (doc):

```
<td><a href="document/' . $row_1['id'] . '.doc' . '" ">' . $row_1['id'] . '</td>
```

Теперь мне необходимо настроит на данном объекте открытие любого файла с любым расширением из каталога

```
<td><a href="document/' . $row_1['id'] . '/' .любое название  .'</td>
```

Как указать "??" -?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filename = reset(glob("document/$row_1[id]/*.*"));
echo "<a href='$filename'>скачать</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь необходимо использовать функцию `opendir()`. Хорошо описан пример работы с функцией [в разделе документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.opendir.php).

В Указанном Вами примере использовать `*.*` не получится!